# Calling a function if document property equals value

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to check if the user has the `isActive` property set to `false`. If it is then I need to sign out the user. I know this is not the best way to accomplish this but it can be changed later. I am doing the following but it says `this` is undefined. How can I call a function from within the `.then`

```js
signOut() {
  this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
    .then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
}

checkIfActive(id: string) {
  return this.afs.collection("users").doc(id).ref.get()
    .then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        if (doc.data().isActive === false) {
          this.signOut(); // <------ says 'this' is undefined
        }
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the `signOut` function from the `thenable` then you need to use [`Arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Instead of `then(function(doc) {` use `then(doc => {`. This will allow `this` access to the originating context.

> Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context

```js
checkIfActive(id: string) {
  return this.afs.collection("users").doc(id).ref.get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        if (doc.data().isActive === false) {
          this.signOut();
        }
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Not totally sure, but `checkIfActive(id: string)` might need to be declared via fat arrow, too

Comment: I think the example is an `Angular` component, so it should work, I hope :)

Comment: @sketchthat it is an angular component. and your solution works thank you!

Comment: No problems. Don't forget to mark the question as solved and select this answer as the solution.

Comment: @sketchthat will be glad to :)

Answer (score 0):

You Can not use 'this' within the "Funtion() {}" because it's not in it's scope. You have to use "() => {}" arrow Funtion .

```js
checkIfActive(id: string) {
    return this.afs.collection("users").doc(id).ref.get()
      .then((doc) => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            if (doc.data().isActive === false) {
              this.signOut(): <------says 'this' is undefined
            }
          } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
          }
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }
```